# AttributeError: int object has no add attribute. In the function of saving the prediction to a json format folder

Tags: python, json, dataframe, machine-learning, nlp

I am writing a function to save a predictive variable to a json file. Initially, the variable was of type array.numpy16 of the form [1,0,1 ... 0, 0 1].
In the function code, I have to add an id to the data.
How do I replace the get parameter or rewrite the function

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=predictions)

def save_output(data, path):
    with open(path, mode="w") as file:
        for line in sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x.get("idx"))):
            line["idx"] = int(line["idx"])
            file.write(f"{json.dumps(line, ensure_ascii=False)}\n")
```

```
   1 def save_output(data, path):
      2     with open(path, mode="w") as file:
----> 3         for line in sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x.get("idx"))):
      4             line["idx"] = int(line["idx"])
      5             file.write(f"{json.dumps(line, ensure_ascii=False)}\n")

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Where you have `x.add("idx")`, where do you expect the value of `x` to come from? What do you think the values of `x` will look like? (Hint: what do you get when you iterate over `data`? For example, if you check `list(data)`, what do the elements of the list look like?)

Comment: For that matter, what do you expect to happen when you `.add("idx")` to that value? Should `"idx"` be a valid thing to `.add` to it? Why? What should the result type be? Does it make sense to convert that to `int`?

Comment: It would help if you could show an example of what the input data looks like,  and what the resulting JSON should look like. In particular, should `line` be a row of the data? A column? Something else?

Comment: Karl i fixed on x.get. I do not know how to change the function of what was added to the folder [{"idx": 0, "}]